# How to store and reference intermediate values for a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have just started learning Haskell in the last few weeks. I am using the Project Euler questions to learn and am currently trying to figure out if something is possible. Not looking for someone to hand me the answer, just need help understanding data structures in Haskell.

I am currently working on [problem 484](https://projecteuler.net/problem=484), which specifies a recursive function. Writing the function wasn't an issue, I currently have:

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

derivative :: Integer -> Integer
derivative x
    | x < 2 = error "Error: Attempt to evaluate outside domain"
    | isPrime x = 1
    | otherwise = (derivative a)*b + a*(derivative b)
    where
        [a, b] = int_split x

--this function find the first pair of divisors
int_split :: Integer -> [Integer]
int_split n = [first_div, n `div` first_div] where
              first_div = fromJust $ find (\x -> (n `mod` x) ==0) [2..]
```

This seems to be working fine as the calculation matched the sample value the problem gives. The issue is that I need to compute this for very large values, getting all values through 5x10^15. Getting all values up to ~10^8 runs pretty quickly but past that it gets pretty slow. Simply using map is definitely inefficient, as it isn't taking advantage of the fact that we could be referencing previously computed values.

My idea was to change my function to store values in a lookup table as they are computed that the function is able to reference. I tried using Data.Map to store values, but I couldn't figure out how to integrate this into my function in a recursive way. Is this possible in Haskell? Or is there a better way that I'm not thinking of to store and use intermediate calculations?

Comment: Lookup "memoization", you should find several examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just didn't know what to look up! My background is stronger in math so I'm a little unfamiliar with some of these concepts.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think optimization of your current approach can get you the answers you're looking for in a reasonable amount of time. Let's suppose you optimize so well that you can compute the solution for any number in a single clock cycle, and let's give you a relatively normal 3GHz processor.

```
$ units
You have: 3 giga hertz
You want: / day
        * 2.592e+14
        / 3.8580247e-15
```

Even at this incredibly fast pace, you can solve only 2.5e14 inputs per day. So it would take you 6 days to compute solutions up to 5e15. But of course even the best optimization of your algorithm will never get you close to that pace. As is often the case with Project Euler problems, you have to do some fancier math to reduce the size of the problem before you can solve it with a computer.

Comment: I think that you're right. I found a way to rewrite the function in terms of its prime factorization that might speed things up. I was mostly just concerned with the idea of storing values, which the other comment about "memoization" seems to address.